# Show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges.

Hint: consider the sum of two subsequent entries.

How can I use that hint to solve the questaion.. ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{?}{(2n-1)(2n)} < \frac{?}{2n^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $1/n - 1/(n+1) = 1/[n(n+1)].$ That shows that if you group this series in pairs, it converges (by the comparison test). You still have some work left to do.

Comment: I got it !!! I solved it. Thank you